# How to create IsDirty inside OnPropertyChange, but at the same time turn it off when entities are loaded from a database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged, dirty-data

I’m building WPF app, and I got to the point where I want to be able to check whether an entity IsDirty, so I found this solution online:

```
private bool isDirty;

    public virtual bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return isDirty; }
        set { isDirty = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(true, propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(bool makeDirty, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        if (makeDirty)
        {
            isDirty = makeDirty;
        }
    }
```

Then I can use it like this

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.DescriptionRequired)]
    [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.DescriptionLength60)]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            if (description != value)
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

And it seems to work, anytime a property is changed the entity will get dirty because OnPropertyChanged is called.
The problem I have is when I load an entity (or collection of entities) from a database, then onpropertychanged is called:

```
SomeEntitiesCollection = new Service().SomeEntities();
```

Then each entity which comes is marked as dirty, and I cannot find anyway around it, apart from going through a loop and setting IsDirty back to false.
Is there anyother way of achieving it?

Regards

Comment: Why do you need `IsDirty` property? For change tracking?

Comment: Because my Entities are in disconnected state, and I want to be able to prompt the user when edit is cancelled, and any of the property was modified.

Comment: Why you can't simply *reset* `IsDirty` after object is loaded from database? Construct it as usual, set properties, `IsDirty == true`, reset `IsDirty = false` (do not call `OnPropertyChanged` obviously), it will stay `false` until property will be changed.

Comment: Since you're using Entity Framework, and Entity Framework already does change tracking, why not simply use that instead of creating your own?

Comment: @Sinatr Hi, this is what I do at the moment, if that is a single entity I set the IsDirty back to false, if that is a collection I go through a loop and set them back. I just though there maybe a way around it, to turn that check before I load them and turn it back on after I load them. But I don't know how to achieve it, and whether there is some kind of pattern for it. I think it is a common scenario for everyone.

Comment: @hvd yes it does, but im using short running contexts, so as soon as entity/ies are loaded i get rid of the context, so there is no tracking.

Comment: @adminSoftDK, I am not using EF, so I am not sure how objects are instantiated. Is there a query what creates objects (construct them with default constructor and setting properties) which you can modify to set `IsDirty = false` at same time?

Comment: @Sinatr hi thanks for the suggestion, but setting it in the constructor will not help, as after it, all properties are set to the values which came from a db, so onpropertychanged is called, and therefore it sets it up to isdirty = true.

Comment: Normally I'd then suggest the `ObjectMaterialized` event, which is supposed to get raised after the properties of the object have been set, but since you're working with non-tracking entities, I'm not sure if even gets raised at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there isn't an easy way

you should override your method that retrieve entities from db in a way that it sets automatically `Isdirty=false` on entity creation.
I used nhibernate interceptor and events to do something similar but it is not your case.

another way is to keep a copy of all the original values and compute the dirtiness when anyone asks for it. So instead of using a isdirty property you should create a method and save an initial state for all properties

Comment: Any code exmple would be usefull, because I don't know how to achieve it. All it does behing the scene is this                                                                  using (var context = new ContextService())
            {
                return
                    new ObservableCollection<Category>(
                        context.Category);
            }

Comment: @adminSoftDK I don't know how entity framework works internally. as I said I use nhibernate. I just give you an hint on where to watch

Comment: @adminSoftDK another way is to keep a copy of the original state of the properties and compare it when you dirtycheck

Comment: Hey, I did the original values and it works great and its simpler as well. Thank you :)